# Why do I get ObjectReference null error, while the parameter has a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

This my code, why do it produces the error?

```
 sMailBody=MailstrBody.ToString();
                    StringBuilder sample = new StringBuilder();
                    sample = MailstrBody;

                                           string passno = dsMail1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PASSNO"].ToString();
                    HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

                    EmailContentDAL example = new EmailContentDAL();
                    example.Pdf(sample, Response, passno);      


     public void Pdf(StringBuilder sample, HttpResponse currentResponse, string passno)
    {

      StringReader sr = new StringReader(sample.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, 
        currentResponse.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
       currentResponse.Clear();
       currentResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
       currentResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GetPass_" + passno + ".pdf");

        currentResponse.Buffer = true;
        currentResponse.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        currentResponse.Write(pdfDoc);
        currentResponse.End();
```

}

The above code produces null reference error at `htmlparser.Parse(sr)`, but at `StringReader sr = new StringReader(sample.ToString())`, `sample.toString()` shows a value.

Comment: Possibly that your String Reader is having HTML tags.

Comment: Yes it's all HTML Design .sample = MailstrBody have HTML Design

Comment: does you string has <hr> tag. it is not supported i think. Once long time back i had this error.

Comment: Can you try this    for HTMLWorker Class Object HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc, new HTMLTagProcessors(), null);

Comment: this might solve your problem but i am not sure. Sorry. Someone else might help you